# can i get udid with ios6 for my enterprise

Tags: ios6, udid

My company uses the UDID to save iphones and determine if they have the right to use certain app.
I heard that on IOS 6, Apple will remove the UDID.

Can I continue to use this system?

Comment: No, I can still see the UDID in the organizer in xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use UDID anymore.  You can still get it from organizer/itunes, but you should upgrade your app to use one of the replacement ID's.

> uniqueIdentifier
>
> An alphanumeric string unique to each device based on various hardware details. (read-only) (Deprecated in iOS 5.0. Use the identifierForVendor property of this class or the advertisingIdentifier property of the ASIdentifierManager class instead, as appropriate, or use or the UUID method of the NSUUID class to create a UUID and write it to the user defaults database.)